# Adding new line to database and unexpectedly closes app

Tags: javascript, android, json, android-asynctask, lampp

I am currently a beginner to android programming and right now I am developing an app to make a JSON connection to a LAMP server and display the JSON data. The connection is currently successfully being made and i can create product and see it in the db but the app unexpectedly close's every time, can someone help and point me in the right direction, will add more if needed.

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    is = null;
    jObj = null;
    json = "";

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        Log.i("url", url);

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            Log.i("url", url);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            Log.i("url", url);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Log.i("Stage 1", "Stage 1");

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");

            Log.i("1 ", line);
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    Log.i("Stage 2", "Stage 2");

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    Log.i("Stage 3", "Stage 3");

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}

public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {


// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.1.165/wp-admin/android_connect/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

> logcat 09-16 10:47:27.285 
>   23440-23458/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp I/OpenGLRenderer﹕
>   Initialized EGL, version 1.4 09-16 10:47:27.287 
>   23440-23458/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕
>   Enabling debug mode 0 09-16 10:47:28.372 
>   23440-23440/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp V/Monotype﹕
>   SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app =
>   com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp 09-16 10:47:28.372 
>   23440-23440/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp V/Monotype﹕
>   Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default 09-16
>   10:47:28.449  23440-23471/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp
>   I/url﹕
>   http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/get_all_products.php 09-16
>   10:47:28.451  23440-23471/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp
>   I/url﹕
>   http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/get_all_products.php?
>   09-16 10:47:28.674  23440-23458/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp
>   D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb7f62f50
>   (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb7f75e00 09-16 10:47:29.017 
>   23440-23471/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp I/Stage 1﹕ Stage 1
>   09-16 10:47:29.022  23440-23471/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp
>   I/1﹕ Unknown database 'download_androidhive' 09-16 10:47:29.022 
>   23440-23471/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp I/Stage 2﹕ Stage 2
>   09-16 10:47:29.023  23440-23471/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp
>   E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value
>   Unknown of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
>   09-16 10:47:29.023  23440-23471/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp
>   I/Stage 3﹕ Stage 3 09-16 10:47:29.029 
>   23440-23471/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>       Process: com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp, PID: 23440
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a
>   null object reference
>               at com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:130)
>               at com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:105)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 09-16 10:47:29.528  23440-23440/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp
>   E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp.AllProductsActivity has leaked
>   window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{78d7c4f
>   V.E..... R......D 0,0-479,116} that was originally added here
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>               at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
>               at com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:117)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
>               at com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp.AllProductsActivity.onCreate(AllProductsActivity.java:57)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5255)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651) 09-16
>   10:47:34.521  23440-23471/com.example.androidhive.productjsonphp
>   I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 23440 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

Your try to parse Json from String "json" but this "json" string give null value, if Please check "json" string is null, before use it.

so, try this code

```
if(json!=null && !json.equals(""))
{
try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
)else{
Toast.makeText(context, "json is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```